# Mocking Method Call in Celery shared_task

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, celery

I have a Celery shared_task in a module `tasks` that looks like this:

```
@shared_task
def task():
    from core.something import send_it
    send_it()
```

and I am writing a test attempting to `patch` the `send_it` method. So far I have:

```
from ..tasks import task


class TestSend(TestCase):

    @override_settings(CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)
    @patch("core.tasks.send_it")
    def test_task(self, send_it_mock):
        task()
        send_it_mock.assert_called_once()
```

When I run this, I get the error: `AttributeError: <module 'core.tasks' from 'app/core/tasks.py'> does not have the attribute 'send_it'`

Out of desperation I've used `@patch("tasks.task.send_it")` instead, as the import happens inside the shared_task, but I get a similar result. Does anyone know how I can effectively patch the `send_it` call? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `core.something.send_it` ?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. You patch where it's used, not were it comes from.